# String and integer comparison AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Tech used:

- PHP 5.4
- AngularJS 1.2 rc2

I'm having an issue when I save a value from a `select` it saves to my DB fine, but when I $http.get the object from my API the `select` in my template does not select the correct option without me converting it to a string first.

```
<select
    class='input-xlarge'
    ng-model='main.newGoal.end_day'
    ng-options='key as val for (key, val) in options.weekDays'>
    <option value=''>-- Select a Day --</option>
</select>
```

I've checked the object from my API and I receive an INT of the correct value but I have convert it to a string to make it select correctly in my html template:

```
$scope.main.newGoal.end_day = $scope.main.newGoal.end_day + "";
```

Before when my API returned numbers as STRINGs the `select` worked fine.  I changed this behavior because AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP does this by default and is my production server.

How do I make "1" == 1 in my html template easily?

### Update

I forgot to add an example of my source:

```
$scope.options = {
  weekDays: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
};
```

I receive something like:

```
$scope.main = {
  newGoal: {
    end_day: 5,
    start_day: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post fiddle/Plunker please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use  `indexOf`.

As example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="options.weekDays.indexOf(selectedItem) as selectedItem for selectedItem in options.weekDays"></select>
    selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.options = {
  weekDays: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
};
    $scope.selectedItem = 0;
}
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/31/)</kbd>

Comment: I am not sure that this would work, because `options.weekDays` is probably an array of names ('Mon','Tue',...) instead of ['1','2',...], and its model seems like the day in the week as an integer. The problem comes from using `ng-options` with `(key, value)` on an array instead of a collection of objects. `key` is supposed to be a property name, but here it is transformed as the index in the array as a string.

Comment: `probably` means no me no you knows exactly what he gets. BTW, the link I posted you this is what he wanted? but it different from what he asks. I asked him to post Fiddle.

Comment: I agree, the question needs to be more detailed!

Comment: I should have been more clear but I was really trying to get this to work in the view without much extra legwork.  I'm using your indexOf method from your comment.

Comment: ok, so ill edit my answer to allow to other users use your/my question/answer. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelCalkins fixed to `indexOf`

Comment: @MaximShoustin I switched the answer to yours, tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I better understand the problem here!

According to the Angular Docs on [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect), `(key , value)` is only when dealing with objects. So when you do `(key, val) in options.weekDays`, key corresponds to a "property name", which is a string. But in your case, you are dealing with an array. In order to make it a number, you would have to parse it first.

I see two ways of doing it (this is without the directive from the previous answer).

Here is the new version of the demo (http://jsbin.com/ORuKike/15/edit?html,js,output)

1) Using a function:

```
$scope.getKey = function(key) {
    // 10 is the radix, which is the base (assumed to be base 10 here) 
    return parseInt(key, 10); 
}
```

The ng-options becomes:

```
ng-options="getKey(key) as val in (key, val) in options.weekDays"
```

2) Using a filter on your array to format it before:

```
app.filter('parseInt', [function() {
  return function(input) {
    var newinput = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function (val, key) {
      this.push({key: key, val: val});
    }, newinput);
    return newinput;
  };
}]);
```

The ng-options becomes:

```
ng-options="item.key as item.val for item in options.weekDays | parseInt"
```

This is similar to what Maxim Shoustin proposed, but it consider an array of names and it is hidden from your controller and can be reused elsewhere as a filter. You could also use the $filter service and call it inside your controller if you prefer.

3) Using `indexOf` as suggested by Maxim Shoustin in the comments below:

```
<select
    class="input-xlarge"
    ng-model="main.newGoal.end_day" 
    ng-options="options.weekDays.indexOf(item) as item for item in options.weekDays">
</select>
```

Here, `item` is the value of the weekday, and we use its position in the array of weekdays as the value of the options, which will be used for the comparison with the model.

**--Initial answer--**

*(I thought that the model was a string, and it could not match an `int` key but it is actually the inverse. The model is an `int` and the key is a string. I'll leave this in case other people encouter this problem.)*

You can use a directive to parse the ng-model value:

**EDIT:** Here is a live demo (http://jsbin.com/ORuKike/3/edit?html,js,output).

**html**

```
<select
    class='input-xlarge'
    ng-model='main.newGoal.end_day'
    ng-options='key as val for (key, val) in options.weekDays' 
    parse-int>
    <option value=''>-- Select a Day --</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
app.directive('ParseInt', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
            controller.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return parseInt(modelValue, 10);
            });

            controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                return '' + viewValue;
            });
        }
    }
} ])
```

The formatter takes your ng-model value and parse it to int for the ng-options comparison. And the parser takes the selected value of the select and convert it back to string.

Comment: I like where you're going with this but when I change the $scope.main.newGoal.end_day to an `INT` (how I receive it) parse-float doesn't select it correctly.

Comment: @jpmorin  I liked your solution but I would write the same with one row without directive, only `indexOf`: http://jsbin.com/ORuKike/9/edit

Comment: Yes good idea, I didn't thought about calling `indexOf` function in the ng-option directive directly.

Comment: The indexOf method ended up being the easiest to implement without really any extra code.  Thanks and credit to jpmorin and MaximShoustin